# Disable rounded avatar

Tags: gitlab

I hate these rounded avatars in Gitlab.  They look ridiculous and cause more problems than they are worth when trying to set logo images and such.  How do I turn that thing off and go back to good old fashioned square avatars?

BTW, I would want to disable them across the board.  Everywhere they are used, I want them gone and back to square.

Comment: Look for imagemagick steps in avatar uploaders.

Comment: Nope, doesn't use imagemagick, it seems some CSS thing somewhere because saving the image from the browser will save a square image.

Comment: Ah, even better. I see that you're almost ready to post a self-answer :)